# fs-extra fails with syntax error when running with systemmd, works fine with node command

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, deployment, node-modules

I am trying to create a service to run a Node.js backend api application on ubuntu to run with systemmd.
I'm stuck on the following error

```
/home/ubuntu/Pdf2t/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/mkdirs/make-dir.js:85
} catch {
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I have read through the internet found that the issue was occuring on fs-extra versions below 9 and node below 10. I'm using fs-extra version 9.0.1 and above with node 14.15.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

The interesting thing is just running the command sudo node index.js works perfectly.

The service is defined as such:

```
[Unit]
Description=PDF to text back-end service
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/Pdf2t/index.js
Restart=always
User=nobody
Group=nogroup
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/Pdf2t

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

All help is appreciated

Comment: Could you give us more context on what you're trying to achieve and the environment that you're trying that on?

Comment: @AhmedMahmoud As written this is running in ubuntu 18, what I'm trying to do is have the node.js application run as a service using the systemmd. Hope this explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update node version to 10 or above, and updating fs-events dependency in this project to 9 or above.

It can work with the node upgrade only, but just incase.

https://github.com/google/docsy/issues/265

Comment: "I have read through the internet found that the issue was occuring on fs-extra versions below 9 and node below 10. I'm using fs-extra version 9.0.1 and above with node 14.15.1 on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"

Comment: Can you double check the version of fs-events and the node instance that systemmd uses?